# 2 column layout missing content

Tags: php, html, css, multiple-columns

Im creating my site and require a 2 column layout on my page.

I have this code available for the one column layout.

```
 <HTML>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php include_once('header.php'); ?> 

            <div class="header_02"><center>one column layout</center></div>

<div style="position:relative">
<div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:30; top:30;">
    <img src="images/xclo.jpg" width="350" height="215">
  </div>  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
    <a href="foo.html"><img src="images/frame.png" width="400" height="400"></a>
  </div>
</div>

column 2 content goes here.          

</div></div>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>  

</body>
</HTML>
```

which displays fine.

however when I change it to this:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php include_once('header.php'); ?> 

            <div class="header_02"><center>2 column layout</center></div>

<div style="position:relative">
<div id="container">
<!-- Start Column 1 -->
<div id="column1">
  <div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:30; top:30;">
    <img src="images/xclo.jpg" width="350" height="215">
  </div>  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
    <a href="foo.html"><img src="images/frame.png" width="400" height="400"></a>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
<div id="column2">
column 2 content goes here.          

</div></div>
<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>  

</body>
</HTML>
```

with this css code in style.css

```
#container {
  float: left;
  width: 98%;
  position:relative;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#column1, #column2 {
  width: 45%;
  float: left; 
  position:relative;
}
          #column1 { 
           overflow:hidden;
          }

          #column2 {
           border-left: 1px solid #000000;
           padding-left:30px;
          }
```

it does not display the column 1 content.

my question to you is this:

how can I get this to work?

am I missing something?

please help me.

thank you.

Comment: Maybe create a jsfiddle for us, would be easy to fix it from there.

Comment: What do you mean to achieve with `position:absolute; left:0; top:0;`? If it just want to fill the whole width and sit at the top in the parent element, you don't need any style code at all.

Comment: tryed it. it does not work

Comment: I think there must be something in your external stylesheet causing issues for you, as this jsFiddle seems to work, per se: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/sgD8Z/ ... though, it doesn't seem to be floating the columns... because they aren't within the same container, it appears.

Comment: Nice. I posted a simple two-column layout below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your layout a bit, you might be able to build on this:

This is HTML:

```
<div>
    <center>2 column layout</center>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="column1">Coumn 1 content</div>
    <div id="column2">column 2 content goes here.</div>
</div>
```

This is CSS:

```
#container {
    font-size: 22px;
}
#column1 {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    background-color: green;
}
#column2 {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
}
```